# VS13 Property Management "No Visual C++ Project Is Loaded"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, properties

I'm having this weird and confusing problem with my property manager. When I open the property manager it just says: **"No visual c++ project is loaded"**. Do any of you have a solution to this? I've searched the web, and not many people seem to have the same problem. The only similar solution I find is on the MSDN forum which tells me: ***"Tools, import and Exports Settings, Reset all settings"*** This doesn't help. ***I've also reinstalled VS***, didn't help either. It also have to be said that **I'm loading a C# project** but it still shows "No Visual c++ project is loaded".

Please help me.

Comment: Did you reset to C#?

Comment: "`I'm loading a C# project but it still shows "No Visual c++ project is loaded"`" <- maybe this?

Comment: @UniCell Thanks bro, I didn't know property sheets didn't exist in C# projects. That's why I couldn't find anything useful on the web, my stupidity is amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was loading a C# project believing I would be able to use to property sheets in it. **The property sheets seems like they're solely for C++ projects**. Thanks up for the help, you lead me to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this "Tools, Import and Export Settings, Reset All Settings". It worked for me